# Reflection to get value of class property in class

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties

I have 2 type of class.

```
public class Info
{
 public string name {get; set;}
 public Address address {get; set;}
}

public class Address
{
 public string addressInfo {get;set;}
 public string country {get;set;}
}
```

**

> Edit:

```
Info info = new Info();
string subClass="address"; 
Type subType = info .GetType().GetProperty(subClass).PropertyType;
string val = typeof(subType).GetType().GetProperty("addressInfo").GetValue(data, null)?.ToString() ?? "";
```

> This is what I want to achieve but I cannot code in this way, cause it
> got error.
> **

Now I want to get the value of addressInfo in Address class that inside Info class by Reflection dynamically. How can I achieve this?
Thanks!!!

Comment: So are these properties actually private, or is this just lazy?

Comment: It's all public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
var info = new Info();

var property = info
   .GetType()
   .GetProperty("address");

string val = (string)property
   .PropertyType
   .GetProperty("addressInfo")
   .GetValue(property.GetValue(info));
```

<sub>***Note** : This is lacking suitable error checking and fault tolerance, add pepper and salt to taste*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, from ur code I find out that this line
.GetValue(data, null) should bcome like this .GetValue(data.Address, null)

But how can I achieve this without code it as data.Address???

Comment: I alrd found a ways to do this, this is the sample code.

.GetValue(data.GetType().GetProperty("address").GetValue(data, null), null)

Thanks!!!!